# How to list all the commands in Drush 9 (aka: drush help)?

Tags: 8, drush

I'm trying to list all the available commands by `drush help`, however I've the error:

```
$ drush help
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]                                 
  Command  was not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to run Drupal-specific commands.
```

It was working in Drush 8, what's the equivalent command in Drush 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly a bug that `drush help` is printing a meaningless error message. Instead, it should tell you how to get the list of available commands.

`drush list` is the way to do that.